# filtering and averaging values in one array based on values in a second array

Tags: javascript

I have two separate arrays: one with the hour at which the measurement was performed and one with the results obtained at that hour. Example: (the real data is much longer)

```
hours =[10,8,13,7,8,12,10,13,23,12] 

results =[101, 104, 101, 106, 101, 107, 109, 110, 112, 107]
```

I plot one against the other and now I need to find the average for each hour. At first I thought this to be a trivial thing to do but it got complicated real fast. I bet there is an easy way to do it, I just can't find it. I searched couple of related questions about it and came up with a solution below. It works but it is slow and surely there is a way to do it better. (Note that for plotting I need to end up with sorted arrays for unique hours and equivalently sorted array containing the averages for each hour).

```
function ave (a) {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++) {
            total += a[i];
        }
        return total / a.length;    
    }

var unique = Array.from(new Set(hours));
unique.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

var arr_res= [];
var build_arr =[];

for (var i = 0; i <= unique.length-1; i++) {
    build_arr.length = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j <= results-1; j++) {
        if (hours[j] == unique[i]) {
            build_arr.push(results[j]);
        }
    }
    arr_res.push(ave(build_arr));
}
```

Comment: is results[] as direcly related to hours array? i mean, is  results[n] = somefunction(hours[n]) ???

Comment: yes, they are linked: the hours array is the time at which the result data has been observed.

Comment: Ok. What is that you want. Your requiremtn is unclear from the qn

Comment: So are there multiple results array??? At each hour??

Comment: I wan to check if anyone knows a method that would do it much faster as the calculation blocks my page loading.

Comment: I'm asking what is the calculation you require.? You qn is unclear Obviously. Is your end result so called average?? what are you trying to average out...

Comment: No. One array for hours and one for results. E.g. at 10 am the result was 101, at 13 one day was 101, another day was 110. I need to average the results at each hour and end up also with two arrays: hours and average_per_hour: so [10, 13] and [101, 105.5] for the example in this comment.

Comment: So you have a results array for each day? and may be after some days you want an average of results array as an array.
Eg: hrs:[10,12,13,15].  day1Results:[101,105,101,102] , day2:[102,106,102,103]; now avgResults shouldbe [101.5,105.5,101.5,102.5].. Is that it???

Comment: @JinsPeter ^Whatever you've asked above is just what I've assumed OP is doing but instead of separate arrays he have all the values combined in just one array for hours and one array for measured value at that hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Iterate over hours array
2. Create an object that would have at it's key the value of hour
3. The value would be the value from results array when you are adding the key first time.
4. When that same key is found subsequently, the average is computed and added as modified value.
5. Push the obj values into an array by iterating the object
6. Sort the array by hour. If this array is enough stop else collect the result in two arrays.

See the solution below:
```

```js
var hours = [10, 8, 13, 7, 8, 12, 10, 13, 23, 12];

    var results = [101, 104, 101, 106, 101, 107, 109, 110, 112, 107];
    var obj = {};
    var avg = 0,
      tempCount;
    hours.forEach(function(v, i) {
      if (!obj[v]) {
        obj[v] = {
          hour: v,
          val: results[i],
          count: 1
        };
      } else {
        tempCount = obj[v].count + 1;
        avg = (obj[v].val + results[i]) / tempCount;
        obj[v] = {
          hour: v,
          val: avg,
          count: tempCount
        };
      }

    });
//You have got averages by now.                                              //Only thing remaining is to get the right output //data structures.


var res = [];
for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    //console.log("Key=" + i, "Val=" + obj[i].val);
    res.push(obj[i]);
  }
}
res = res.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.hour - b.hour;
});
var hourRes = [],
    avgRes  = [];
res.forEach(function (v, i) {
  hourRes.push(v.hour);
  avgRes.push(v.val);
});

console.log(hourRes, avgRes);
```

Comment: @Nick Doesn't my solution help? Are you looking for something else?

Comment: It works and is fats but I did preliminary speed tests and it seems that your method is on par with mine at least for short datasets up to a couple of hundred points.  @abhishekkannojia's seems to be the best performing one so far.

Comment: @Nick Not sure, how you tested it. However, look at this perf test `http://jsben.ch/#/sBhtN`. This test is for 200 entries. For 1000 elements `http://jsben.ch/#/iyQUa`. Both the tests seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I did the performance.now in the browser. Not sure if this is the best method. Indeed yours seems to be much faster on jsben.ch

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this by combining `Array.reduce()`, `Array.map()` and `Object.keys()` :

```js
var hours =[10,8,13,7,8,12,10,13,23,12];

var results =[101, 104, 101, 106, 101, 107, 109, 110, 112, 107];

var groups = hours.reduce(function(acc, hour, idx) {
  acc[hour] = acc[hour] || [];
  acc[hour].push(results[idx]);
  return acc;
}, {});

//console.log(groups);

var averages = Object.keys(groups).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a-b;
}).map(function(key) {
  return groups[key].reduce(function(sum, val) {
    return sum+val;
  }) / groups[key].length;
});

console.log(Object.keys(groups).sort(function(a, b){return a - b;}));
console.log(averages);
```

Comment: Did you understand the qn? I did not??

Comment: @JinsPeter Not perfectly. But I just assumed both the arrays `hours` and `results` will have one to one correspondence.

Comment: @JinsPeter No `results` array is his observed value at the hours. So at `hour[i]` the observed value is `results[i]`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Damn it is complicated. I need some time to go through it. Would you say it can be faster than going through the two for loops?

Comment: @Nick Performance wise I would say Yeah its a bit faster since it uses a hasmap to store the measurement value at an hour instead of looping thorough whole loop again and comparing each and every value.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia could you define what is the average result array he expects?. I couldnt figure out dude

Comment: @JinsPeter In the code if you uncomment the `console.log(groups)` you will see the array of values at each hour. The final average result array is basically the set of average values of each these arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then the following should work:

Output for the following is :

**

> 7-106, 8-102.5, 10-105, 12-107, 13-105.5, 23-112

**

```
var hours = [10, 8, 13, 7, 8, 12, 10, 13, 23, 12];
var results = [101, 104, 101, 106, 101, 107, 109, 110, 112, 107];

function toObject(names, values) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        result.push({ hour: names[i], result: values[i]});
    return result;
}

function average(arr) {
    var sums = {}, counts = {}, results = [], name;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        name = arr[i].hour;
        if (!(name in sums)) {
            sums[name] = 0;
            counts[name] = 0;
        }
        sums[name] += arr[i].result;
        counts[name]++;
    }

    for(name in sums) {
        results.push({ name: name, value: sums[name] / counts[name] });
    }
    return results;
}

function Test() {

    var result = toObject(hours, results);
    var averagess = average(result);

    for (var i = 0; i < averagess.length; i++) {
        console.log(averagess[i].name + '-' + averagess[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will need to check for speed but it seems to me that the code in my question (which works) would have similar performance, no?.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't compare the two methods for performance. If you want to get rid of the FOR loops though you should look into http://underscorejs.org/. Will most likely perform better too.